# A SpriteRenderer is not displaying the sprite when set the second time

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a cell prefab in which I have a GameObject with SpriteRenderer. I am instantiating multiple instances of a prefab and feeding a sprite for every instance. The first cell instance is displaying the given sprite but the second one is not.

Here I am creating two instances of a `Cell` and feeding the Cell with a sprite from `mIconManager`:

```
private void PopulateCells()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        GameObject goPrefab = Instantiate(goRawPrefab, CalculateCellPosition(i), Quaternion.identity, trBoard);
        CellController cellController = goPrefab.GetComponent<CellController>();
        cellController.FillContent(mIconManager.getSprite(i), i);
    }
}
```

This is a snippet from `CellController` script attached to a `Cell`:

```
private void Awake()
{
    mIcon = GameObject.Find("IconSprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    mCardBg = GameObject.Find("CardBg").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

public void FillContent(Sprite sprite, int index)
{
    mSprite = sprite;
    mIcon.sprite = mSprite;
}
```

This is my `Cell` prefab:

[image]

When I run the code, the second instance of a prefab is not getting the sprite.

[image]

I checked the first prefab's `SpriteRenderer` in the inspector while the game is running, and it said `anchovies` for the sprite - the one I gave via `FillContent()` method. Interestingly, the second prefab's `SpriteRenderer` component shows `EMPTY` sprite.

First Prefab's SpriteRenderer while game is running:

[image: First Prefab's SpriteRenderer while game is running]

---

---

---

Second Prefab's SpriteRenderer while game is running:

[image: Second Prefab's SpriteRenderer while game is running]

Am I missing something? I searched through the internet and found some posts saying "SpriteRenderer is not loading sprites the second time" but they were not answered and the ones that were answered didn't solve my problem.

P.S. I also tried setting the SAME sprite for both instances of the `Cell` prefab - still no success.

P.S.2. I logged the sprites that are given to the both instances of the `Cell` prefab and they were not null or empty. I even did `Debug.Log(mIcon.sprite)` which both instances logged the name of sprites I provided.

Edit:

Logging when giving the same sprite to both instances:

```
    public void FillContent(Sprite sprite, int index)
    {
        Debug.Log("hop, spriteName : " + sprite + ", prefabIndex : " + index);
        mSprite = sprite;
        mIcon.sprite = sprite;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Filling It with the same sprite twice the code seems fairly normal
This will Help me debug it al lil more ie.

```
private void PopulateCells()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        GameObject goPrefab = Instantiate(goRawPrefab, CalculateCellPosition(i), Quaternion.identity, trBoard);
        CellController cellController = goPrefab.GetComponent<CellController>();
        cellController.FillContent(mIconManager.getSprite(1), i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, but still no success. Cannot post an image in the comments section, I will update the question in a minute.

Comment: I updated the question. Gave both of them an apple sprite. Still the second one is empty

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out the problem was not related to the SpriteRenderer. SpriteRenderer was working as expected. However, the way I got a reference to the SpriteRenderer was not correct.

In `CellController`, I was getting a reference to the SpriteRenderer with `GameObject.Find...`, the thing is it was not giving me a reference to a instantiated prefab clone, but to the first prefab clone.

```
private void Awake()
{
    mIcon = GameObject.Find("IconSprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    mCardBg = GameObject.Find("CardBg").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
```

Instead, I used `tranform.Find` and everything worked as expected.